# Add image to ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How can I add an existing image to my ASP.NET MVC project? The image is not being displayed, it works fine when I copy the url directly from Google, but when I save it to my PC and then try to add it, it doesn't work.

I've tried this code

```
<i> 
    <img src="C:\filename.txt\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Images\cars.jpg" class="card-img" alt="..." > 
</i>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there are probably some errors in your browser's developer tools console!

Comment: You don't want to be hard coding the absolute path to your `C:` drive, instead make the path relative something like `src="\Images\cars.jpg"`

Comment: I'd suggest a relative path, as @user20716902 pointed out, too. That will spare you much trouble when publishing the application elsewhere. In case you really need to hard code a path to your local filesystem, you'll have to share the folder; the path would by something like this then: `//name_of_your_machine/name_of_the_share/cars.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer i needed, "Move your image into wwwroot folder and use ~/cars.jpg, because ASP.NET Core gets static files from only wwwroot folder. Thanks!

Comment: Or better yet, you can move your images into a folder called `images` in your wwwroot folder, and then use `~/images/cars.jpg`